# Some Doubts about Recursion in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, recursion

btw its a tic-tac-toe game in python and it is a snippet that handles that the user does not put invalid code or does not try to add there X or O in the place that is already taken.
so the instructor in the online video said that you can use while loop to check the above listed problems so i thought why not use a recursion whenever user inputs something wrong and and now it is showing something weird in the output

```py
def handle_turn(player):

    position=input("Chooes a position from 1 to 9: ")
    if position not in ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]:
        print("Invalid Choice")
        handle_turn(player)
    # while position not in ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]:
    #     position=input("iNVALID CHOICE Chooes a position from 1 to 9: ")

    position=int(position)-1
    if board[position]!="_":
        print("you cannot go there")
        handle_turn(player)
    board[position]=player
    display_board()
```

output:

Chooes a position from 1 to 9: 1
X | _ | _
_ | _ | _
_ | _ | _
Chooes a position from 1 to 9: 2
X | O | _
_ | _ | _
_ | _ | _
Chooes a position from 1 to 9: 3
X | O | X
_ | _ | _
_ | _ | _
Chooes a position from 1 to 9: 1
you cannot go there
Chooes a position from 1 to 9: 9
X | O | X
_ | _ | _
_ | _ | O
O | O | X
_ | _ | _
_ | _ | O
Chooes a position from 1 to 9: 1
you cannot go there
Chooes a position from 1 to 9: 8
O | O | X
_ | _ | _
_ | X | O
X | O | X
_ | _ | _
_ | X | O

Comment: You might want to sketch out function calls. Once a function is called. the next statement following it is executed. Use the return construct to ensure no further code execution happens after recursion ends.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `handle_turn(player)` with `return handle_turn(player)`.

### Explanation

Why is this important? Consider the following recursive function:

```py
def f(n):
   print(' '*n + 'beginning of call {}'.format(n))
   if n < 5:
     f(n+1)
   print(' '*n + 'end of call {}'.format(n))
```

Executing this function gives the following output:

```
>>> f(0)
beginning of call 0
 beginning of call 1
  beginning of call 2
   beginning of call 3
    beginning of call 4
     beginning of call 5
     end of call 5
    end of call 4
   end of call 3
  end of call 2
 end of call 1
end of call 0
```

As you can see, once execution of call 5 is over, the flow returns to call 4, which executes its remaining statement `print(' '*n + 'end of call {}'.format(n))`; then flow returns to call 3, etc.

Because there is no `return` statement in this function, **all** statements in the function will be executed. Statements which are written before the recursive call `f(n+1)`are executed before the recursive call, and statements which are written after the recursive call are executed after the recursive call has returned.

In the case of your function `handle_turn`, you don't want to execute the remainder of the function if a recursive call was made. To prevent that from happening, you can add a return statement immediately after the recursive call. Consider:

```py
def g(n):
   print(' '*n + 'beginning of call {}'.format(n))
   if n < 5:
     g(n+1)
     return
   print(' '*n + 'end of call {}'.format(n))
```

or equivalently:

```py
def g(n):
   print(' '*n + 'beginning of call {}'.format(n))
   if n < 5:
     return g(n+1)
   print(' '*n + 'end of call {}'.format(n))
```

The output of this new function will be:

```
>>> g(0)
beginning of call 0
 beginning of call 1
  beginning of call 2
   beginning of call 3
    beginning of call 4
     beginning of call 5
     end of call 5
```

As you can see, the remaining statements of calls 0 to 4 were not executed, because the `return` statements inside the `if` cut short to the execution of these calls.

If you want to practice and have fun with recursive functions that have no return statements and always execute all their remaining statements after a recursive call, I suggest the game "RoboZZle" about a robot controlled by recursive functions, which you can play online. The hardest puzzles make heavy use of this behaviour of recursive functions.

### Tail recursion

In the previous paragraph, I said that the one line `return g(n+1)` and the two lines `g(n+1) \\ return` are equivalent. In most languages this would not be strictly true, because one of those two expressions uses *tail recursion*, whereas the other does not. Python does not have tail recursion at all, so this distinction doesn't matter here.

One consequence is that you can expect programs that make heavy use of recursion to be rather slow in Python, or even to crash in some cases. It's not a problem in your example, because recursion depends on user input, and the user will always be slower than your program if the user is a human. But it could be a problem if the user was another program.